# junitparameter exception object of class

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junitparams

I have a junit test.
I'm using JUnitParamsRunner in spring 4.1 and I can't resolve the problem.

I want to run the test with the object and make more like this test. 
but in every run I getting the same error. when I looked for other result in google, I saw same way like I did and for them the tests work fine.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: While trying to create object of class class java.lang.String could not find constructor with arguments matching (type-wise) the ones given in parameters.
    at junitparams.internal.InvokeParameterisedMethod.createObjectOfExpectedTypeBasedOnParams(InvokeParameterisedMethod.java:84)
    at junitparams.internal.InvokeParameterisedMethod.castParamsFromObjects(InvokeParameterisedMethod.java:66)
    at junitparams.internal.InvokeParameterisedMethod.<init>(InvokeParameterisedMethod.java:37)
    at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestClassRunner.buildMethodInvoker(ParameterisedTestClassRunner.java:125)
    at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestClassRunner.parameterisedMethodInvoker(ParameterisedTestClassRunner.java:118)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.methodInvoker(JUnitParamsRunner.java:482)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:273)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:446)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:393)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.String.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2152)
    at junitparams.internal.InvokeParameterisedMethod.createObjectOfExpectedTypeBasedOnParams(InvokeParameterisedMethod.java:81)
    ... 20 more
```

the test code:

```
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;
import junitparams.naming.TestCaseName;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CheckAccountTests extends UserActionBaseTests {

   private final static String accountQueryParamName = "account";
   private final static String regionNameQueryParamName = "regionName";
   private final static String regionName = "regionTest";
   private final static String nonExistentEmailAccount = "nonexistentemailaccount@cnoga.com";
   private final static String nonExistentRegionName = "nonExistentRegionName";
   @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
   private final String emailAccount = "dani@cnoga.com";


   @Test
   public void dummyTest() throws Exception {
       for(int i = 0; i< 1000 ; i++) {
           i++;    
       }
   }


   @Override
   public final String get_relativeUrl() { return super.get_relativeUrl() + "/checkAccount.action"; }


   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   private Object[] checkAccount_DifferentAccounts_ShouldSucceed_ParametersToTest() {
       return new Object[]{
               new Object[]{"Existent email account", emailAccount, regionName}};
   }

   @Test
   @Parameters(method = "checkAccount_DifferentAccounts_ShouldSucceed_ParametersToTest")
   @TestCaseName("{0}.  Account: {1}, Region: {2}")
   public void checkAccount_DifferentAccounts_ShouldSucceed(String account, String regionName) throws Exception {

       var result = (ExceptionResult) sendRequest(getQueryParams(account, regionName), HttpStatus.OK, SysConstant.SUCCESS);

       assertThat(result.getMsg()).isEqualTo("true");
   }

   private List<NameValuePair> getQueryParams(String account, String regionName) {

       return new ArrayList<>() {
           {
               add(new BasicNameValuePair(accountQueryParamName, account));
               add(new BasicNameValuePair(regionNameQueryParamName, regionName));
           }
       };
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   private List<NameValuePair> getQueryParams(String account) {

       return getQueryParams(account, regionName);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `checkAccount_DifferentAccounts_ShouldSucceed_ParametersToTest()` method produces three parameters for each test execution:

```
"Existent email account", emailAccount, regionName
```

Your test method accepts only two parameters:

```
checkAccount_DifferentAccounts_ShouldSucceed(String account, String regionName)
```

You need to make sure that the number of parameters produced by the provider method matches the number of parameters that the test method accepts.